# Can wordpress serve as a Firebase website

Tags: wordpress, firebase

This might have already been asked or a question not for this site but I couldn't find an answer to it anywhere.

I recently have been working on a website that will use the Firebase hosting and I was wondering it a Wordpress site would work for this?

Obviously Firebase would no longer host it, but is it easy enough to link Firebase to wordpress? And I don't mean link it so that users can see blog posts updated by Firebase. I mean link wordpress and firebase so that users can login and create accounts on the wordpress site and it authenticates with Firebase, users can read data (strings, bools, numbers, ect) from Firebase and it'll fill in textfields and images on Wordpress.

Basically using Wordpress as a platform the same as Android or iOS.

Comment: Firebase Hosting can only serve static web sites, or (by connecting it with Cloud Functions) web sites running on Node.js. Wordpress is running PHP code, so cannot be run on Firebase Hosting. Whether you can connect an existing Wordpress site to a Firebase project is a whole different matter, and rather broad. It's likely possible, since we're dealing with software here. Whether it's feasible mostly depends on the exact Firebase products you're looking to use (there are about 18of them), your skill level in PHP and the Firebase products and protocols, and the time you're willing to spend.

Comment: Would you recommend to write the static website or use wordpress for it? Or a mix of both as I only want it to serve as a website for an app, but have it be made quick enough. I also have very little knowledge in php and more in HTML and CSS.

Comment: Recommending technologies is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you want to learn whether Firebase is enough for your needs, I recommend you take the [web focused codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). It may take some time, but will quickly show Firebase fits your needs.